# Trouble with formatting input as JSON format with java

Tags: java, if-statement

Hi all I have a trouble with my java program. Essentially I'm writing a program that asks the user for a book's title, author, price, and isbn. Then it takes the input that stores it to my Book class that stores the input and has a toString method that prints out the contents similar to JSON formatting.
Then my books class uses an Array list to store the Book objects and has a toString method that prints out the entire set of books in JSON format. Problem is it doesn't format it properly. The problem lies within my if and else statement in my code. Heres my code:

---

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Books
{
  private ArrayList<Book> books;

  public Books()
  {
    books = new ArrayList<Book>();
  }
  public void add(Book bk)
  {
    books.add(bk);
  }
  public String toString()
  {
    String temp = "{\n ";
    temp = temp + "  \"books:\": [\n";
    int bookCount = 0;
    for (Book bk : books) {
      temp += bk.toString();
      bookCount++;//add +1 to bookcount
      if (bookCount < books.size()-1) {
        temp += ",\n";
      }
      else {
        temp += "\n  ]\n}\n";
      }
    }
    return temp;
  }
}
```

---

When I run my program it looks like this:

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4QdH.jpg)

My goal is to have it look like this:

[WantedResults](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2NMO.jpg)

So after parsing the first book correctly by adding the ",\n"; . But each book being parsed after it adds the "\n  ]\n}\n"; which I only want to be added to the last one. :( Please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you increase the `bookCount` value before the checking condition.

If you are not using enhanced for loop, the code will look like this

```
for (int bookCount = 0; bookCount < books.size()-1; bookCount++)  {
    Book book = books.get(i);
    //  print book
    //  check Condition
}
```

bookCount should be added after checking condition

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that, use a proper `JSON` library to properly parse or create the JSON data structures.

Here is a tutorial to get you started. 
http://java.sg/parsing-a-json-string-into-an-object-with-gson-easily/

Comment: Thanks for the heads up but for my case I have to parse it this way :\

Answer (score 0):

Use [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes):

```
...
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper ();
mapper.writeValue (new java.io.Writer ().write (jsonifiedStr), books); 
System.out.println (jsonifiedStr);
...
```